# Why a function without returning value has a value in perl?

Tags: function, perl

I'm trying to undestand why a function without a value being returned has a value defined. Could someone explain?

This is the code:

```
perl -le 'sub xxx { print 2; } print defined(xxx);'
```

The console output is:

```
2
1
```

I was expecting that the value returned was undef and a defined value....

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[print](http://p3rl.org/print) is documented to return a value:

> Returns true if successful.

And subroutines are documented to return the last expression evaluated when no explicit [return](http://p3rl.org/return) is present.

> (In the absence of an explicit return, a subroutine, eval, or do FILE automatically returns the value of the last expression evaluated.)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that maybe perl has something like None (I dont have a value) and NULL (I have a value that is no value).

Comment: @RicardoLucca it does have `undef` which is similar to those, but that doesn't have anything to do with this case.